# MVC5 not setting authentication cookie value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies

I took an empty MVC5 project, added some code to it, eventually built up to a small authentication system. I started out with what I knew - the good old forms auth, but I noticed that the .ASPXAUTH cookie passed in Set-Cookie was empty and the expiration date was set to unix epoch. I assumed it was an issue with MVC5 and swapped it out to Owin - but the problem seems to remain, the cookie passed into client still looks like this:

`Set-Cookie:.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT`

The owin authentication part looks like this (simplified):

```
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
        },
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role.Name));
_authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        IsPersistent = true,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now,
    }, claimsIdentity);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {area = "Catalog"});
```

I've removed the FormsAuthentication module and disabled default forms authentication in web.config.

Am I missing something here? The simplified moving parts of my project look almost identical to the default MVC 5 template with auth, just not using identity...

Comment: Why do you set the ExpiresUtc property to Now instead a future DateTime?

Comment: That was to prove that the expiration date of the cookie did not get affected